# Java Stream, How to use below code in java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

can any one please help me convert in java stream?

```
private List<String> takeAllPages(Long iId, String clientId, List<PageSummaryList> pages) {
    IssueHeader issuetHeader = issueApi.get(iId);
    String issueSub = issueHeader.getSubject();
    Set<String> samplePageNames = new HashSet<>();
    for (PageSummaryList samplePage : pages) {
        String entityId = "issue-" + clientId + "-doc-" + samplePage​.getName().replace(" ", "-");
        List<TickType> tickList = tickTypeApi.getTickForEntity(EntityType.DELL_SOP, entityId);
        for (TickType​ tickType : tickList) {            
            String tickName = tickType​​​.getName();
            if (issueSub.contains(tickName)) {
                samplePageNames​.add(samplePage.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    return Lists.newArrayList(samplePageNames);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What errors are you getting?  What documentation about java streams have you read?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not provide every class that your code uses i could not test it, but here is an implementation that should work (or with some minor fixes would work).

```
private List<String> takeAllPages(Long iId, String clientId, List<PageSummaryList> pages){
        IssueHeader issuetHeader = issueApi.get(iId);
        String issueSub = issueHeader.getSubject();

        return pages.stream()
                .flatMap(sp -> {
                    String entityId = "issue-" + clientId + "-doc-" + sp.getName().replace(" ", "-");
                    return tickTypeApi.getTickForEntity(EntityType.DELL_SOP, entityId).stream();
                 })
                .filter(tickType -> !issueSub.contains(tickType.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

**EDIT** In the base code there some conceptions errors (i did not see some details in you requirements, sorry for that) but i have made another version and i will keep the first implementation just for reference.

Here is the correct code i think xD (test it and we will figure it out).

```
private List<String> takeAllPages(Long iId, String clientId, List<PageSummaryList> pages){
    IssueHeader issuetHeader = issueApi.get(iId);
    String issueSub = issueHeader.getSubject();
    // Until here it is the same as the code you provided
    // This code should do the exact same as yours but using Streams API.

    // Using the @stream() method i am converting your @pages list (List<PageSummaryList>) to
    // a Stream<PageSummaryList>, so that i can perform various operations upon every item in that list (@pages).
    return pages.stream()
            // Firstly i am converting every PageSummaryList into a Pair (javafx.util.Pair but if you want you can create your own).
            // This pair contains a PageSummaryList and its corresponding Stream<TickType>, basically your first for loop.
            // After this map operation i will have a Stream<Pair<PageSummaryList, List<TickType>>>.
            .map(sp -> {
                String entityId = "issue-" + clientId + "-doc-" + sp.getName().replace(" ", "-");
                List<TickType> stream =  tickTypeApi.getTickForEntity(EntityType.DELL_SOP, entityId);
                return new Pair<PageSummaryList, List<TickType>>(sp, stream);
             }) 
             // Here i have Stream<Pair<PageSummaryList, List<TickType>>>
             // and i want only to keep those where their List<TickType> contains an element whose name is in @issueSub
            .filter(pair -> {
                return pair.getValue().stream()
                    .filter( tp -> !issueSub.contains(tp.getName())
                    .count() > 0;

            })
            // Now i want only the names (its basically i want the Stream<String> (it is in someway your Set<String>
            .map(pair -> pair.getKey().getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // this is what you want to return, a List<String> (equal to your return statement.
}
```

Comment: hi really Thanks, for this code ... above code, i did not get value for samplePage.getName() & tickType.getName()

Comment: there is a typo, sorry, instead of samplePage.getName() it should be sp.getName(), i have fixed it. take a look.

Comment: first i need to add the samplePageNames as a Set.. and return the value as List

Comment: is there any restriction about what you can use? because that way you are creating a set just to later convert it to a list, also is the solution i gave you not working ? what is the problem ?

Comment: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: private List<String> takeAllPages​(Long iId, String clientId, List<PageSummaryList> pages​) {
    IssueHeader issuetHeader = issueApi.get(iId);
    String issueSub = issueHeader.getSubject();​​
    return (List<String>) pages.stream().flatMap((sp -> {
        String entityId = "issue-" + clientId + "-doc-" + sp.getName().replace(" ", "-");
        return tickTypeApi.getTagsForEntity(EntityType.DELL_SOP, entityId).stream();
    }).filter(tickType -> !issueSub.contains(tickType.getName()));
}​

Comment: are you having compile time or runtime errors ? at eyesight this code would compile and would do what you want. unless there are some problems in your custom classes

Comment: no i dont have any compile time or runtime errors, its not returning the list of  pages ;  if (tagNameSet == null || tagNameSet.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            sopPageList = takeAllPages(iId, clientId, pages);;...input its passing like (1,"SuperClient","SuperClient Doc_1")

Comment: so you are saying it is returning an empty list ? are you passing a List with actual objects to the takeAllPages method ?

Comment: The think here is
i have the issueTicket subject, and list of pages 
1st step
i need to iterate list of pages
2nd--> need to take entity tag list based on page
3rd--> then check the condition whether issueTicket subject.contains(tag.getname)
(Ps: one page contains multiple tags)
if yes add page name add to Set and need return as a list

Comment: pageSummaryList.stream().flatMap(sp->{
    String entityId = "client-" + clientCode + "-page-" + sp.getName().replace(" ", "-");
    List<Tag> tagList = tagApi.getTagsForEntity(EntityType.SAMPLE_SOP, entityId);
    tagList.forEach(tagName -> {if(ticketSub.contains(tagName.getName()))
    sopPageNames.add(sp.getName());
    });​
});​...........i tried this , can you please help me to resolve using stream

Comment: the code that i provided as the same functionality as you described, i'll edit so to explain more

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support, but the problem is  returning the null value , Error : java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: Thanks.. for ur continuous support. Now i got correct value using your code and mean while we tried below code.....

Comment: return pages.stream()
            .map(PageSummaryList::getName)
            .map(name -> name.replace(" ", "-"))
            .map(name -> "issue-" + clientCode + "-doc-" + name)
            .flatMap(entityId -> tickTypeApi.getTagsForEntity(EntityType.DELL_SOP, entityId).stream())
            .map(TickType::getName)
            .filter(issueSub::contains)
            .distinct()
            .collect(toSet());

Comment: this code is a bit cleaner, in the sense that your lambdas have less body, which is very good, usually lambda expressions should be two lines of code at maximum, you could problably transform those 3 map operations into a single one.