# Java Stream - Read POI Sheet in parallel using Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, apache-poi

I'm reading a POI Sheet from input file, ranging from 80-400 entries with first cell containing integer codes:

```
| CODE |
| 112  |
| 112  |
| 113  |
| 114  |
...
```

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of each `CODE`. For that I'm iterating lines one by one using iterator, using a `HashMap` to make a entry when iterator finds non-existant `CODE` or increment the counter if `CODE` exists in the HashMap:

```
var sheet=WorkbookFactory.create(new File("file.xlsx")).getSheetAt(0);
var codeMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
var iterator=sheet.iterator();
iterator.next();
while(iterator.hasNext()
{
    var cell=iterator.next().getCell(0);
    if(cell!=null)
    {
        var code=new DecimalFormat("00").format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        codeMap.computeIfPresent(code,(key,val)->val+1);
        codeMap.putIfAbsent(code,1);
    }
}
codeMap.forEach((key,value)->System.out.println("Code: "+key+", count: "+value));
```

I'm trying to turn the above code into `parallelStream` to quicken up the process, I'm having a hard time understanding it. I'm sure this can be done, but I don't know how.

Thus far I only understand to create a stream:

```
var stream=Stream.of(sheet).parallel();
HashMap<String,Integer> codeMap=stream.filter();     //map? filter? stuck here
```

I tried reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255064/java-stream-how-to-use-below-code-in-java-stream) question, but didn't understand what's happening.

Comment: Why? There's only one file; only one disk; only one I/O stream. Making it parallel won't (can't) make it faster.

Comment: @user207421 doesn't creating parallel stream create copies of the stream, increasing I/O stream counts? if one stream can search from the beginning, and one from end, that'll halve the time taken.

Comment: No. Dunno where you got that idea. The stream still has to be read from beginning to end. No way you can halve that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read Excel worksheets using Apache POI via `java.util.stream.Stream` the [Sheet.spliterator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#spliterator--) can be used to create a `Stream<Row>` using `StreamSupport`.

Then  `Stream.map` can be used to get a `Stream<String>` with all the contents of one column. For that the `Function` in `Stream.map` needs to get all contents of that column for each row as `String`. To get cell contents as `String` [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) should be used to be independent of different cell types.

Having that one can collect that  `Stream<String>` using the groupig-by-collector having function identity and counting-collector. That gets a  `Map<String, Long>` as the result.

Complete code example:

```java
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class ReadExcelUsingStreamsCountOccurence {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
  // from 5.2.0 on the DataFormatter can set to use cached values for formula cells, so no formula evaluation needed
  dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  
  try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream ("./Excel.xlsx");
       Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn); ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

   boolean parallel = false;
   //boolean parallel = true;
   Spliterator<Row> spliterator = sheet.spliterator();
   Stream<Row> stream = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, parallel);
   Map<String, Long> codeMap = stream.skip(1)
    .map(row -> dataFormatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
   ;
  
   System.out.println(codeMap.getClass());
   System.out.println(codeMap);

  } catch(Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
}
```

Hints:

The `stream.skip(1)` is to skip the heading row.

Using that code you can benchmark whether running that in parallel or not will have any influence. It should not have any significant influence.

Why not simply always using parallel stream?

Using a parallel stream is not always faster than using a sequential stream. Synchronization brings its own costs. So first criteria for the decision whether to use parallel stream or not is to benchmark. There is no way around.

And  running parallel may be error prone on the contrary as neither the Java Collections framework nor Apache POI are synchronized by default.

In above example [Stream.collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) is thread-safe per default, even if the Java Collections framework, i.e. `java.util.HashMap` is not. And the `Function` of [Stream.map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) only reads from one sheet of the workbook. That also should be thread-safe, even if Apache POI is not thread-safe per default.

So above example should run without problems using `boolean parallel = false;` as well as `boolean parallel = true;`. But first criteria for the decision whether to use parallel stream or not is to benchmark. Why using a more error prone approach if it not has any advantages?

Comment: In which scenarios will running the spliterator in parallel mode not be error prone?

Comment: @MakdaMujji: The Spliterator is not error prone. The Spliterator API was designed to support efficient parallel traversal in addition to sequential traversal. The problem is the Collections framework, i.e. `java.util.HashMap`, and Apache POI, which are not designed to be thread-safe.

Comment: I see. POI isn't thread-safe, so that'll always be a hazard.